# Как разбить массив на подмассивы неравной длины?

Tags: javascript

Так можно разбить массив на подмассивы равной длины, а как сделать чтобы длина каждого последующего подмассива в childArray была в n (допустим в 2 раза) длиннее предыдущего ( `[[1,2], [3,4,5,6], [7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14],..]`)?

```
let array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15];
let split= 2; 
let childArray = [];
for (let i = 0; i <Math.ceil(array.length/split); i++){
    childArray[i] = array.slice((i*split), (i*split) + split);
}
console.log(childArray);
```

Comment: А в чем проблема-то? И что за код вы привели?

Comment: Проблем больше нет, разобрался (спасибо за примеры), код для наглядности вопроса.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Test](https://playcode.io/139632?tabs=console&script.js&output)

```
let array = [];
for(let i = 0; i < 100; i++) 
  array[i] = i;

let start = 0; 
let mult = 3; 
let split = 1; 
let i = 0;
let childArray = [];
while (start < array.length) {
    split = split * mult;
    childArray[i++] = array.slice(start, Math.min(array.length, start + split));
    start = start + split; 
}
console.log(childArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var ar = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15];
var count = 2; //сколько элементов должно быть в подмассиве и во сколько увеличиваем следующий
var start = 0;
var end = count;
var childArray = [];
while (start < ar.length){
  end = ((start < 1) ? end : (end * count + count));
  childArray.push(ar.slice(start, end));
  start = end;
}
console.log(childArray);
```

Comment: если не трудно, подскажите за что минус ?